# Add column in query using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, average

I have three tables.

**tblcandidates**

```
candidateid     |     candidatename
1               |     Abc
2               |     Def
```

**tbljudges**

```
judgeid         |     judgename
1               |     Stack
2               |     Overflow
```

**tblscores**

```
scoreid         |     candidateid     |     judgeid     |     swimsuit
1               |     1               |     1           |     100
2               |     1               |     2           |     99
3               |     2               |     1           |     100
4               |     2               |     2           |     93
```

I am using this query to get the average of each candidate.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (c.candidateid) AS c,
    candidatename AS NAME,
    j1.swimsuit AS j1,
    j2.swimsuit AS j2,
    (
        j1.swimsuit + j2.swimsuit
    ) / 2 AS average
FROM
    tblscores,
    tblcandidates c
LEFT JOIN tblscores j1 ON c.candidateid = j1.candidateid
AND j1.judgeid = 1
LEFT JOIN tblscores j2 ON c.candidateid = j2.candidateid
AND j2.judgeid = 2
WHERE   tblscores.candidateid = c.candidateid;
```

**Output**

```
c      |      name       |      j1       |      j2       |     average
1      |      Abc        |      100      |      99       |     99.5
2      |      Def        |      100      |      93       |     96.5
```

My problem is what if the judges become 3. I want to make my query dynamic depending on the number of judges. My query is limited to 2 judges only. I also want to display the judges scores like in my output for the proof that they have a score.

Comment: Please share an sql fiddle. This is a MySQL pivot table problem.

Comment: how to make an sql fiddle?

Comment: Here's a sample [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fd52/1/0)

Answer (score 3):

You are re-inventing the wheel here by implementing the average calculation yourself. Instead, you could use MySQL's builtin aggregate [`avg`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function. If you really want all the scores too, you could use [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to display them:

```
SELECT   c.candidateid AS id, 
         candidatename AS name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(swimsuit) AS all_scores,
         AVG(swimsuit) AS average_score
FROM     tblcandidates c 
JOIN     tblscores s ON c.candidateid = s.candidateid
GROUP BY c.candidateid, candidatename
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot that i have to display all the judges scores too. like in my output.

Comment: @SeeMore The `group_concat` call will display all the individual scores. If you need them in different columns, you have no choice but to keep adding more items to your select list like you have done so far.

Comment: okay.. I tried it. all scores is there with comma, thank you.. maybe i'll just use explode to get them all in php for now. I'll wait for some other answers but your answer is helpful. Thank you.